# How do I write into a read-only folder on windows using ubuntu in WSL?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, permissions, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to install stuff on the arcgis version of python, but because ArcGIS installs its python executable and environments inside program files, `conda` in ubuntu WSL throws back:

```
EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: /mnt/c/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgis
  uid: 1000
  gid: 1000
```

I have tried adding metadata to my wsl.conf, but running `sudo chmod +rwx /mnt/c/Program\ Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/` after that still throws back:

```
(arcgis) virgilxw@kiki:/$ sudo chmod +rwx /mnt/c/Program\ Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/
[sudo] password for virgilxw:
chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/c/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/': Permission denied
```

I've also tried to remove the read-only tag in Windows via properties on the whole Python folder, but that doesn't change anything either.

Comment: Which stuff are you installing?

Comment: Did you install Anaconda in Program Files or somewhere else?  If you try installing it in ProgramData, to which everyone has write permissions, it might work

Comment: I'm installing the usual suite of scipy stuff;

Comment: @cup my anaconda is on my WSL linux system

Comment: So when you installed Anaconda on WSL you chose Program Files/Anaconda3?  The default is /root/conda

Comment: It's running off of the ubuntu install -